Distancing/hedging expressions
I came across this question in an exam. I believe the option understood is the correct answer because I think after that we need a cluse and a clause cannot begin with to.
Am I missing something?
The question was:
The boat is...... To have left Miami last Saturday morning.
A) understood
B) said that

You are missing nothing. Both 'The boat is understood to have left Miami...' and 'The boat is said to have left Miami...' are possible, but because exam choice (B) contains 'that', only the first choice (A) is correct. To correctly fill the blank, you need a  participle, e.g. believed, understood, said, etc.
